# Nuxt 3: Get element of slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Below is the code of my **component**, I am using **VueUse** too, and I want to trigger the "**onClickOutside**" function of vueUse if the click is made outside the slot element.

But not able to get the perfect element unlike Nuxt 2, it's not working!

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen fixed inset-0 p-5 bg-gray-300/75 z-50">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  mounted() {
  
    onClickOutside(this.$slots.default()[0], (event) => {
      this.$emit('close')
    })

  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `onClickOutside()` on the wrapper instead of the slot, since the `this.$slots.default()[0]` could be `null`

---

```js
<template>
  <div
    ref="wrapper"
    class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen fixed inset-0 p-5 bg-gray-300/75 z-50">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>

import { onClickOutside } from '@vueuse/core';

const emits = defineEmits([
    'close'
]);

let clickoutsideObserver: ReturnType<typeof onClickOutside> | undefined;

const wrapper: Ref<null|HTMLDivElement> = ref(null);

clickoutsideObserver = onClickOutside(
    wrapper,
    () => {
        emits('close');
    }
);

// destroy the observer to save the memory
onBeforeMount(() => {
    clickoutsideObserver? clickoutsideObserver() : null;
});

</script>
```